# How was the initial jump made?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-tomorrow-war

I just watched *[The Tomorrow War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tomorrow_War)*. I actually have quite a few questions but I will start with just this one.

In the movie, fairly early on it is explained that time travel is only possible between the current year (2022) and the future where the war is occurring (2048). This is because there is a time link between these two points in time: they move forward in time together with a fixed 'distance'. You can't, for example, jump from 2048 to 2035.

But at the beginning of the movie there is no time link initially in 2022. The people from the future appear to the people in the present by jumping through a time portal in the middle of a soccer game. I thought they needed a time link? Did I miss something? I'm not following how the initial jump was made given the film's explanation of how the time link works.

Comment: *"But at the beginning of the movie there is no time link initially in 2022"* No, it's in 2048 leading **back** to 2022. That's the one the people from the future take.

Comment: But how did they establish it at specifically 2022? It seemed like they picked that time period specifically. Which seems to conflict with the rules they described in the film.

Comment: They didn't pick 2022, the jump picked it for them.

Comment: With time travel movies, you just need to allow for illogical things. This movie, like many of its kind, falls apart if you think too much about it.

Comment: It was explained that the time machine was a rough prototype, hence they couldn't jump to any point they wanted and had to make do with what they got, which apparently was the year 2022.

Comment: @Nukesub To quote the Pitch Meetings videos when the question is asked why something implausible occurs: "So the movie can happen."

Comment: @Oliver_C Ah - okay that seems to be the missing detail for me. So it could have jumped back to 1000 BC but they just got lucky it happened to be ~30 or so years prior.

Comment: I don't think this question needs details, but it probably gets downvoted because for many users something is obvious which for the OP isn't so: is that a reason to close it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you're asking how they arrived in 2022 without a "receiver" time travel device.

The answer is: They don't need this.

Much like when they are sent to the future, they do not arrive at a "landing pad" - it's just a set of pre-programmed coordinates, set up by the "sender". To explain further, there are no "receiver" devices, only "sender" devices.

The device in the future is set up in a base in the middle of the ocean. The team from 2022 was supposed to be sent to Miami Beach (which failed due to a system error, throwing off the coordinates). If they were supposed to arrive at some kind of pre-built device, they would arrive in the middle of the ocean, which be a big issue for deployment.

So, what happened is:

- Time travel was invented in 2048, and a team was sent to the past. They set the location via coordinates, to the soccer games because they knew a lot of people would be watching.
- The team sent back consisted of scientists, primarily, that would be able to build *another* time travel device, to send people to the future, from 2022.
- Drafted troops would then be sent to coordinates set by the deployment team, from 2022.

There is never any requirement for the coordinates to be "preset", or any kind of "receiver" pad for time travel to work.

Comment: What is the source for your theory? IIRC the movie says something about the two points being tethered, which would suggest a coupled sender and receiver.

Comment: @BCdotWEB they explain that the points in time are both moving forward together. That's why they can't simply send Dan back to the start of the war with the toxin